# Java 8 Stream - is it possible to use object after mapping is done in the next line?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

We began to upgrade our code to Java 8 which is new in team. I was told to do refactor of a method which is presented below:

```
    for (Operation so : operations) {
        OperationIndex operationIndex = Transformer.getOperationIndex(so);

        if (operationIndex.getServiceOperationNumber() != null) {
            invoice.getOperationNumbers().add(operationIndex);
            Occasion occasion = so.getOccasion().get(0);

            //here's some logic using occasion and invoice

            invoice.setDate(occasion.getDate());
            //some more methods using occasion...
        }
```

I was trying a lot of things to make it work but all of them failed. After all I come to this solution:

```
    operations.stream()
    .filter(so -> Transformer.getOperationIndex(so).getServiceOperationNumber() != null)
    .forEach(so -> {
        invoice.getOperationNumbers().add(Transformer.getOperationIndex(so));
        Occasion occasion = so.getOccasion().get(0);

        //here's some logic using occasion and invoice      

        invoice.setDate(occasion.getDate());
        //some more methods using occasion...

    });
```

But I'm still wondering if it's best solution in this case. Can this be done in less lines of code? Thanks

Comment: Do not use stream where you do not need to, and where it not brings any improvements. First of all - do not create multiline lambdas.

Comment: ...and if you REALLY have to create multi-line lambdas, you can extract a single lambda to a function that returns `Stream`

Comment: @Peter777 that's a bad suggestion on how to refactor this code... return `Stream`?!  He should simply extract the lambda to a separate function and refer it by method reference.

Comment: I'm wondering why you think that fewer lines are possible? Most of the lines contain your application code, if you can reduce that sure, otherwise, no.

Comment: one big problem in your new code is that you called `Transformer.getOperationIndex(so)` twice.  How does `occasion` get populated? What are you trying to improve by the code change? (just for the sake of using new feature is not an improvement)

Comment: @AdrianShum thanks for the really good tips. We have a lot of legacy code to refactor and some of it looks horrible. We are trying to do streams wherever logic allows us to because... well that's the client need. Don't think that we are brainlessly refactor every for into stream - we do negotiate but client wants us to make application logic as much modern as it can be. I'll make it the way You suggested. Seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main problems I see with people migrating to Java 8 is that they get the syntax, but not the idea. I jokingly refer to it as the UPS guy who delivers Christmas presents to American soldiers in Iraq, and tells his neighbors that he's been in a war zone. Technically, he's right, but then not quiet.

You posted only a snippet, so any "optimization" is going to be limited. That said, let me make some general comments, and then I'll post my version of your code.

1. I've nothing against multiline lambdas. I've yet to see any literature that says lambdas must be one-liners, or hell will break loose.
2. It's not clear where `invoice` is created. If it's created in the `if` block, that's good. If it's created somewhere above, and keeps being mutated in different code blocks, not so much. And God forbid if it's sent to the method as an argument (the evil "out" parameter). You may be better off using the [Content Enricher](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DataEnricher.html) pattern, where `invoice` is enriched by transformers along the hop.
3. I tend to avoid using `forEach` with streams as it indicates a `void` method, which indicates side-effect, and is very hard to test. In my experience, most usages of `forEach` can be replaced with something else.
4. Your refactored code isn't necessarily an improvement over your original one; if your client wants you to write "modern" code, whatever that means, you should consider a lot more than just changing syntax. Don't be that UPS guy!

   ```
   operations.stream()
   .map(so -> new SimpleImmutableEntry(so, Transformer.getOperationIndex(so)))
   .filter(t -> Objects.nonNull(so.getValue().getServiceOperationNumber()))
   .map(t -> {
       Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
       // here's some logic using occasion and invoice

       return invoice;
   })
   ```

Comment: Wow that's some high quality answer - thanks for that and especially for the Enterprise Integration pattern links - got some little reading and I'm thinking about further research. I find it extremely useful. However ``invoice`` is created outside this stream and even outside this method(so that pattern can be really helpful)). I will work with this code a little more but thanks anyway for great tips!